# How to cancel a kotlin coroutine and make sure it was cancelled

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, coroutine, cancellation

How can I make sure the coroutine was in fact cancelled, and did not just return or was cancelled by other means?

There is an obvious race-condition between checking job state and invoking `cancel()`. How can I know it was in fact cancelled?

```kotlin
val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).async { delay(1) }
if (!job.isCompleted)
  job.cancel()
```

Comment: Maybe `runBlocking { job.join() }`?

Comment: I'm a little confused with the question. Do you need to verify the job has been cancelled after you cancel it; or do you need to verify the state of the job before cancelling it?

Comment: I need to verify the job has been canceled by me. Let's say I would like cancel() to return false if it was beaten by something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way, but one way is to cancel the job with a very specific exception and then check if it was cancelled with exactly the same exception. This is fairly easy if using `Deferred` as in your example:

```kotlin
suspend fun main(): Unit = coroutineScope {
    val job = GlobalScope.async {
        delay(1.seconds)
        println("Done")
    }
    launch {
        delay(1.seconds)
        println("Cancelled #1: " + job.cancelAndCheck())
    }
    launch {
        delay(1.seconds)
        println("Cancelled #2: " + job.cancelAndCheck())
    }
}

suspend fun Deferred<*>.cancelAndCheck(): Boolean {
    val e = CancellationException()
    cancel(e)
    join()
    return getCompletionExceptionOrNull() === e
}
```

At least on my machine I sometimes see it was cancelled by #1, sometimes by #2 and sometimes by none (completed successfully). As this is a race condition, it may be hard or even impossible to reproduce on other computers.

Surprisingly, I don't see a similar API for the `Job`. Obviously, we can't get a result from `Job`, but I don't see why `getCompletionExceptionOrNull()` couldn't be added at the `Job` level, not `Deferred`. The only way I found is by using the `invokeOnCompletion`, but if feels a bit hacky:

```kotlin
suspend fun main(): Unit = coroutineScope {
    val job = GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(1.seconds)
        println("Done")
    }
    launch {
        delay(1.seconds)
        println("Cancelled #1: " + job.cancelAndCheck())
    }
    launch {
        delay(1.seconds)
        println("Cancelled #2: " + job.cancelAndCheck())
    }
}

suspend fun Job.cancelAndCheck(): Boolean {
    val e = CancellationException()
    cancel(e)
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        val handle = invokeOnCompletion { cont.resume(it === e) }
        cont.invokeOnCancellation { handle.dispose() }
    }
}
```

Both solutions probably require additional testing for various cases like non-cancellable jobs, etc.

Comment: `getCompletionExceptionOrNull` is still `ExperimentalCoroutinesApi`, maybe there is still time to move it to `Job`.